# Cisco SF500-24P Image Upgrade to 14088 fails

Tags: cisco, upgrade

I try to upgrade the system to 1.4.0.88 and it fails with error

Status:  Copy failed 
Error Message:  Copy: SW code file is over sized

I am using HTTP for the upgrade.    Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to TFTP (you will need to install and run a TFTP server probably on your workstation)

Select Boot
Install file
sx300_boot-13506.rfb

After rebooting it should work.  You can also upgrade to 1.4.1.03

Comment: I always use to put files on any linux system and use sftp instead of tftp when upgrade Cisco SMB s devices.